# Copying and Pasting

Tags: gezel-stealing

I want to make a video about how the Zohar knew the Earth was round and had many other information about the Earth they could of never known. According to sources, would copying the verses of the Zohar from a website and pasting them in my notes (iPhone application) be considered stealing? Please cite sources. Thanks.

Comment: Free sources are free and there are a lot of free websites with Zohar

Comment: All depends on the terms of service of the website. Ask them!

Comment: IOW, there’s no copyright on the Zohar per se, but an individual/institution’s translation or rendering of it may be protected and likely varies by jurisdiction.

Comment: Around the mid-300's BCE the Greeks, Aristotle, for one, figured out the Earth was round from star observation, and even had a pretty good guess at it's circumference.

Comment: @Gary the circumference was only calculated by eratosthenes http://www.hakirah.org/Vol25Bogacz.pdf

Comment: @DoubleAA - oh, sorry, missed the mid 300's BCE(I did write "around") by a few dozen years. It's still a few hundred years from Rashbi's time and a good thousand plus years from when the Zohar was "rediscovered" and publicly copied and distributed for profit by the most honest of our forbears, Moses de Leon.